# Multithreading- Problems with the interaction of objects methods in different threadings in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm doing a pong in python witout a graphical interface , only with ASCII characters. To do this I created two threads one for the ball and other for the
racket, but when the racket gets an input the program starts to go crazy and the ball starts to behave very strange. If i don't input nothing to the racket, the program runs fine.

```
import time
import os
import getch
import sys
import threading
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000000)
getch = getch._Getch()
lock = threading.Lock()

class Stick(object):
    def __init__(self,posy = 25,posx = 19):
        self.posy = posy
        self.posx = posx

    def move(self):
        x = getch()
        if x == b'k' and self.posy <= 44 :
            lock.acquire()
            self.posy +=2
            os.system('cls')
            print('\n'*(self.posy-5)+
                '''
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                ''',end='')

                  ##'\n'*(50-self.posx-2),end='')
            lock.release()
            return self.move()

        elif x == b'j' and self.posy > 5 :
            lock.acquire()
            self.posy -= 2
            os.system('cls')
            print('\n'*(self.posy-5)+
                '''
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                |||
                ''',end ='')
                  ##'\n'*(50-self.posx-2),end ='')
            lock.release()
            return self.move()



class ball(object):
    def __init__(self,posx = 53 ,posy= 25):
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy

    def move(self,tipox = -1,tipoy = 0):
        os.system('cls')
        self.tipoy = tipoy
        self.tipox = tipox
        self.posx += self.tipox
        self.posy += self.tipoy
        print('\n'*(self.posy-1),' '*(self.posx-1),'O',self.posy ,sep='')
        return self.encontro(self.tipox,self.tipoy)


    def encontro(self,atual_tipox,atual_tipoy):
        self.atual_tipox = atual_tipox
        self.atual_tipoy = atual_tipoy
        lock.acquire()
        if self.posx <= (obj1.posx):
            if self.posy == obj1.posy:
                lock.release()
                return self.move(tipox = 3, tipoy = 0 )
            x = (self.posy - obj1.posy)
            if  x <= 4 and x>= -4 :
                lock.release()
                return self.move(tipox = 3, tipoy = x)
            lock.release()
            return self.move(atual_tipox,atual_tipoy)
        elif self.posy >= 50 or self.posy <= 0 :
            lock.release()
            return self.move(atual_tipox,(-atual_tipoy))
        elif self.posx >= 213 or self.posx <= 0 :
            lock.release()
            return self.move((-atual_tipox),atual_tipoy)
        lock.release()
        return self.move(atual_tipox,atual_tipoy)


obj1 = Stick()
baLL1 = ball()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target = baLL1.move)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target = obj1.move)
thread2.start()
thread1.start()
```

Comment: This probably isn't your immediate problem, but: You should use a `while` loop to implement an infinite loop in Python. Using recursive calls like this means that after about 1000 frames you're going to fail with a `RecursionError`.

Comment: Also, if you use `with lock:` instead of `lock.acquire()`, it will automatically be released when you leave the `with` statement, so you don't need to put separate `lock.release()` calls all over the place (and you don't risk abandoning the lock if you get an exception, or just forget to `release` on one code path).